# Is there any simple way of interfacing with Twitter/OAuth using PHP?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

*I am losing my mind here.*

*Im looking at a beginners OAuth php package that has a 700 line file. Im used to using 10-12 lines of CURL or just a couple lines with simpleXML to get the same data. Is there a very meat and potatoes way to convey the concepts of interfacing with twitter via oauth without totally alienating someone?*

*Im used to learning by downloading an example, and tooling around with it. The only examples i can find are so confusing that id have to take a course to begin to understand the DEMO.*

**Specific Question:**

I have a users access token. The api address is

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.xml
```

How do i take the token, and mash it into the address and make that give me the data that i want? Im willing to learn, but i cant learn if i dont understand what is going on to begin with. I get the basics, you send a request, user approves, you get a token, i get that. I dont get how you make the requests with your token as authorization in place of the plain text user and pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt exactly the same, but then I found [EpiTwitter](http://wiki.github.com/jmathai/twitter-async) which makes the whole process much, much easier. Checkout the authors blog for specific examples that actually work :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered looking at one of the Twitter API PHP libraries [listed on the Twitter API wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Libraries#PHP)?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this library, but someone posted a link to simple [OAuth library](http://github.com/jamierumbelow/oAuthify/tree/master) few day ago here.